# Centering contents in a <div>

Tags: html, center

I am trying to center text and images on a "content" div. I tried (margin: 0 auto;) and couple more and still not getting it. Also trying to center the div on the screen.

CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
}

#content img {
    width: 50%;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

#content img:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="images/intro_7.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a div in a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Comment: Nope, the img tag works differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `#content`, add `text-align:center;`:

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Use `table` and `table-cell` to center is horizontally and vertically.

Surround your HTML with three div as follows:

```
<div class="outter">
<div class="center">
<div class="inner">
```

**CSS:**

```
.outter {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/URZA4/1)**

More info **[here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html)** for vertical alignment.

**Note:** IE7 and below do not support `display:table;` or `display: table-cell;`

Comment: Awesome, thank you. That did center the content, but how could I center the div on the screen now?

Comment: Horizontally and vertically?

Comment: Is there a more accurate way than margin-top: 50%; ?

Comment: Yeah! In the center of the screen/page.

Comment: Don't care about IE7. Big thanks. Spent an hour trying to figure it out.